# React Material-UI TextField with preloaded value does not move the label (label overlaps with the TextField content)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have Material-UI TextField:

```
<TextField id="gen_ref_num" className="col-6 form-control-sm" label="Number" variant="filled" value={this.props.invoice.gen_ref_num} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
```

And `this.props.invoice.gen_ref_num` has the value already preloaded. Unfortunately, the label overlaps with the content. When I am start editing the field, then the label moves upside and sits in the right position (no overlap anymore). How to ask Material-UI TextField to respect the pre-loaded values and to move label upwards?

Answer (score 2):

The following code is the answer:

```
InputLabelProps={{ shrink: !!this.state.value }}
```

When adapted to the code in the question, the code ir:

```
InputLabelProps={{ shrink: !!this.props.invoice.gen_ref_num }}
```

More is written about this at https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/13013

Comment: I thought this is issue happens when value is `null` ? is this the same case?

Comment: I am not sure. If the value is null, then it is OK, if the label sits in the content place/position, it is so by design.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap with form fixed this issue for me. It should be like this:

```
<form autoComplete="off">
    <TextField ... />
</form>
```